# Drag And Drop problems in Firefox with labels

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop

I have the following markup

```
<li id="task-3" class="form-group task" draggable="true">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><input class="task__checked" type="checkbox" id="task-input-3"></span>
        <label class="form-control task__content" for="task-input-3">content....</label>
        <span class="input-group-addon task__delete">
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

I need to drag and drop such elements. The implementation of D'n'D that I uses works correct in Chrome, but in FF the drag events don't fire. After a few hours I have figured out that the reason in the mark up, particular in the label.

Labels bind with the checkboxes and instead of doing drag and drop they try to check the checkbox. If I try to drag text in label it the element drags, but if I try to drag outside the text in the label it won't work.

[image: Screenshot]

This works in FF

```
<li id="task-3" class="form-group task" draggable="true">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><input class="task__checked" type="checkbox" id="task-input-3"></span>
        <span class="form-control task__content" for="task-input-3">content....</span>
        <span class="input-group-addon task__delete">
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hhyaw53t/

Shorted version. It doesn't replace the elements but shows the pseudo-dragged element http://jsfiddle.net/ut1pyf3x/

Comment: Everything works for me (Fx). What’s your Firefox version?

Comment: @Xufox FF 36, Mac OS. Try to drag near by the label's text [screenshot](https://yadi.sk/i/UM1BzQ0ff8Uzu)

Comment: Now I get what you mean. Please insert your screenshot in your question then.

Comment: @Xufox I added shorted version to exclude the version of wrong working script http://jsfiddle.net/ut1pyf3x/

Comment: Firefox issue : https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1179286